# Fail to build docker image using multi-stage

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build docker image using multi-stage.

The problem is that if I use the same base image, an error occur.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  dev_mac:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        CLANG_URL: ${CLANG_URL}
        CMAKE_URL: ${CMAKE_URL}
        NODEJS_URL: ${NODEJS_URL}
        GIT_URL: ${GIT_URL}
        NVIM_URL: ${NVIM_URL}
        GCC_URL: ${GCC_URL}
    hostname: dev
    container_name: dev
    image: dev
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      # used to access container via ssh
      - 20022:22
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS builder

ARG HOME=/root
ARG BIN_DIR=${HOME}/.bin

ARG NVIM_DIR=${BIN_DIR}/nvim
ARG GIT_DIR=${BIN_DIR}/git
ARG CMAKE_DIR=${BIN_DIR}/cmake
ARG GCC_DIR=${BIN_DIR}/gcc
ARG CLANG_DIR=${BIN_DIR}/clang
ARG NODEJS_DIR=${BIN_DIR}/nodejs

ARG CARGO=${HOME}/.cargo/bin/cargo

### Start from the home directdory ###
WORKDIR $HOME
### Make directories ###
RUN mkdir -p \
  ${NVIM_DIR} ${GIT_DIR} ${CMAKE_DIR} ${GCC_DIR} ${NODEJS_DIR} ${CLANG_DIR}

### install packages ###
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install sudo \
                       curl \
                       wget \
                       cmake \
                       build-essential \
                       ninja-build \
                       dh-autoreconf \
                       libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
                       libexpat1-dev \
                       gettext \
                       libz-dev \
                       libssl-dev \
                       install-info \
                       libtool-bin \
                       pkg-config \
                       unzip \
                       git \
                       jq

### Install clang (Binary release) ###
ARG CLANG_URL
RUN wget -C ${CLANG_URL} -O clang_tar && \
    tar xvf clang_tar --strip 1 -C ${CLANG_DIR} && \
    cd $HOME && rm -rf clang_tar

### Install CMAKE (Binary release) ###
ARG CMAKE_URL
RUN wget -c ${CMAKE_URL} -O cmake_tar && \
    tar xvzf cmake_tar --strip 1 -C ${CMAKE_DIR} && \
    cd $HOME && rm -rf cmake_tar

### Install NODEJS (Binary release) ###
ARG NODEJS_URL
RUN wget -c ${NODEJS_URL} -O nodejs_tar && \
    tar xvf nodejs_tar --strip 1 -C ${NODEJS_DIR} && \
    cd $HOME && rm -rf nodejs_tar

### Install GIT (Compile) ###
ARG GIT_URL
RUN mkdir git_temp && \
    wget -c ${GIT_URL} -O git_tar && \
    tar -zxf git_tar --strip 1 -C git_temp && \
    cd git_temp && \
    make configure && \
    ./configure --prefix=${GIT_DIR} && \
    make -j all && make install && \
    cd $HOME && rm -rf git_tar git_temp

### Install NEOVIM latest (Compile) ###
ARG NVIM_URL
RUN git clone ${NVIM_URL} && \
    cd neovim && \
    make CMAKE_EXTRA_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${NVIM_DIR} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" -j && \
    make install && \
    cd $HOME && rm -rf neovim

### Install GCC (Compile) ###
ARG GCC_URL
#RUN mkdir gcc_temp && \
    #wget -c ${GCC_URL} -O gcc_tar && \
    #tar xzf gcc_tar --strip 1 -C gcc_temp && \
    #cd gcc_temp && \
    #./contrib/download_prerequisites && \
    #mkdir build && cd build && \
    #../configure --prefix=${GCC_DIR} \
                 #--enable-languages=c,c++ \
                 #--disable-multilib && \
    #make -j 8 && make install && \
    #cd $HOME && rm -rf gcc_tar gcc_temp

### Clear cache and change shell ###
RUN apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/cache/* && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/log/* && \

FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG HOME=/root
ARG BIN_DIR=/root/.bin

WORKDIR $HOME

COPY --from=builder ${BIN_DIR} ${HOME}
```

The output of `docker-compose --env-file .env.mac build dev_mac` is:

**failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: circular dependency detected on stage: builder**

I couldn't understand the error message.

Why can't I use the same base image?

As far as I know, the base image desribed in `FROM` is just the base image to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I try building an image from your `Dockerfile` using `docker-compose build`, I get the following output:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.05kB                                                              0.0s
 => WARN: Empty continuation line found in: RUN apt-get clean &&     apt-get autoclean &&     apt-  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                     0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: circular dependency detected on stage: builder
ERROR: Service 'dev_mac' failed to build : Build failed
```

That `WARN:` line is important; if we look at your `Dockerfile`, we find:

```
### Clear cache and change shell ###
RUN apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/cache/* && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/log/* && \     # <-- THIS LINE HERE

FROM ubuntu:latest
```

That erroneous `\`  at the end of the line with no continuation is causing the following `FROM ...` line to be ignore, so Docker thinks your `COPY --from=builder` command is running *inside* the `builder` stage.

Everything works correctly if you fix the syntax:

```
RUN apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/cache/* && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/log/*

FROM ubuntu:latest
```

---

But an even better solution is just to remove that entire block. There's no point in running `apt-get clean` (etc) because you're building a multi-stage image. Only the final stage matters; everything else is discarded.

In a single stage image, running a `apt-get clean` like that is only useful if you run it in the same `RUN` command as your `apt-get install`, etc; otherwise it will actually *increase* the size of your image.